# Why Hawking radiation emission rate inversely proportional to black hole mass?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

The rate of Hawking radiation emission increases as the mass of the black hole decreases, what I don't understand is that if the emission method is related to zero-point energy particles appearing and one half of the pair being captured, why is it that when the surface area of the event horizon would be greater for a larger black hole the Hawking radiation doesn't increase?

Comment: Because the quantum fluctuations captured / emitted / tunneled out have a similar wavelength as the diameter of the black hole.  Smaller black hole means shorter wavelength means higher energy particle.

Comment: Brandon : Why did you not post this comment as an answer?